# Trigger Github Actions only when PR is merged

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a github actions yaml file as follows:

```
name: Test deployment
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
    - name: Random name
      run: date
```

When I raise a PR from a branch to `master` branch, `Github Action` gets triggered. So, I updated my YAML to:

```
name: Test deployment
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
    - closed
    branches:
    - master
```

Now it is triggered when I merge the PR rather than while raising it. But it also gets triggered when I close the PR without merging it.

I found nothing like `merged` type in [docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull-request-event-pull_request)

Even the following syntax i tried does not work as expected:

```
jobs:
  ...
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
```

Can anyone pls help me out here?
Is it possible for me to check if the PR is approved by atleast one reviewer? (I can enable branch protection, but wanted to know if any option exists for doing it in github actions)

Comment: How did you go about checking if PR was approved by atleast one before merging ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but I think it might work as I noticed this is automerge action that must check if the PR is approved before it merges it.

Try to react to this action

```
on
  pull_request_review:
    types:
      - submitted
```

then get from the payload something called `review.state`, it should have value `approved`. I saw it in action here https://github.com/pascalgn/automerge-action/blob/135f0bdb927d9807b5446f7ca9ecc2c51de03c4a/lib/api.js#L123

Comment: I can not understand why the OP chose this answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Agreed, the answer from @michael seems more appropriate and native to workflows. However, the OP mentions _(I can enable branch protection, but wanted to know if any option exists for doing it in github actions)_. While action is often used interchangeably with workflow, they are not quite the same (made more confusing by the dropdown menu titled **Actions** and not **Workflows**), OP may have intended it to mean an individual action. Also, with the branch protection being disabled, criteria may be missing that OP did not want the workflow to run on a push w/o PR merge.

Comment: In my answer I focused on this requirement mentioned in the question

> Can anyone pls help me out here? Is it possible for me to check if the PR is approved by atleast one reviewer?

In my reply I linked code where `review.state === "approved"` shows you can at least check if PR was approved

Answer (score 164):

There is no pull-request-merged event.

The closest thing you can get is to subscribe to `push` event, since a merged PR will always create a push event to the branch it's being merged onto.

If you only care about PRs to `master` then you can specify that:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

The other thing you can do is filter on each step individually

```
      - name: Do something
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true
        run: ...
```

(Edit, as of 2022)
Per the [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-when-a-pull-request-merges), this should be possible now via:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  if_merged:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo The PR was merged
```

Comment: `if: github.event.pull_request.merged` should be enougth.

Comment: This doesn't help me, my job is being skipped.I want to deploy my develop branch on Heroku once the PR is merged into it. Seems like nothing works

Answer (score 44):

While there is no specific `merged` type for pull requests, there is however a `merged` flag on the [API response](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#get-a-pull-request). This allows you to run actions only on merges, rather than all pushes to the target branch.

This would allow one to do the following, assuming we want to run an action on any merge to the `main` branch:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - main
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  my-action:
    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
    runs-on: ...
```

Comment: Documentation as of today confirm this one here, see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-when-a-pull-request-merges

Comment: And what if I want this workflow to utilise `workflow_dispatch`? How to deal with `if`?

Comment: Do I need to add this if statement on every job action? 
Example: 
jobs:
  my-action:
    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
    runs-on: ...
  next-action:
     if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
     runs-on: ...
  last-action:
     if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
     runs-on: ...

Answer (score 6):

Check the github action documentation, seems there is a solution for this,
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-when-a-pull-request-merges-1

```
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  if_merged:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo The PR was merged
```

Comment: Does this run on the branch from the PR or on the target branch fo the PR?

Comment: This runs on the branch from the PR, not on the target branch after merge

Answer (score 2):

So, I just tried the proposed solution and looking at the output I see something strange: the workflow gets triggered but I see that it runs *on the branch being merged*, not on the branch being merged into (`main` in my case).

This is a bit disturbing as my workflow is building and pushing Docker images. What if there are changes on main that are *not* on the branch being merged? It seems to me that the image being pushed might not exactly be what I was expecting??

My workflow runs are here: https://github.com/Axual/ksml/actions - you can see that one workflow was run on `main` (triggered by `push`), the other on a branch.

Is there a way to run a workflow on a push that resulted from a PR merge, or something like that?

Answer (score -2):

Once merged a PR request will commit with a message 'Merge pull request <your PR, etc>'. You can then use that with an if statement of your job.

```
name: build-on-merge

on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
jobs:
  build-on-merge:
    if: startsWith(github.event.head_commit.message, 'Merge pull request')
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
```

Comment: sorry, don't want to be harsh but terrible and error prone solution if you think your solution is the best solution which test based on the commit string message!

Comment: Furthermore the message text is editable on merge, so the merging user could set the message to whatever value.

Answer (score -2):

Old question still popping up on Google. As per Github documentation found here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-a-workflow-when-a-pull-request-is-approved

This is how it's done:

```
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]

jobs:
  approved:
    if: github.event.review.state == 'approved'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "This PR was approved"
```

Comment: This will run when someone approves the PR, not when it's merged as the OP asked.