# How to set GitHub action on closed (but not merged) PRs

Tags: github, github-actions

My question is on the 2nd side of [Trigger Github Actions only when PR is merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710209/trigger-github-actions-only-when-pr-is-merged)
I want to run a GitHub action only on closed - but not merged! PRs.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
    types: [ closed ]
```

jobs:

How can I set the condition?

Answer (score 4):

There is no special type for merged or not-merged events for Pull Request.
Both will be handled via `closed` type as you have it already in your example.

The trick is to look into event details, by doing:

```
jobs:
   build_only_when_pr_not_merged:
      if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action ==
   'closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged == false
```

Workflow will be executed regardless, but you can skip some jobs based on `github.event.pull_request.merged` value.

Comment: that is very spammy on the list of GitHub Actions :(

Comment: Well there are no other working solutions as far as I know :)