# Run a step in a GitHub Actions job only when main branch got changed while developing PR

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I got a workflow that will be triggered every time there's a change in the current dev branch for the PR.

However, there is one of the step that does not need to be run every time as it takes a long time to run. It will only need to be run when there's a change to the `main` branch (usually from when there's another PR that got merged to `main`) or when the resource starting to become old (let's say a day old).

The goal is to skip this step as much as possible during the development and only run it when there's a change to the production.

I'm not sure if either of the condition is possible.

The closest thing I could find is from [Trigger Github Actions only when PR is merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710209/trigger-github-actions-only-when-pr-is-merged)

This is how my current workflow looks like

```yaml
name: on-pr-update

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  on_pr_update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
          cache: 'pip'

      - name: Upgrade pip
        run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

      - name: Install Python dependencies
        run: python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Clone resources <<-- THIS STEP
        #TODO: run only if main branch got changes or once a day
        run: clone_resources
```

**Update 1**: Add example workflow and rephrase description

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: You have a workflow that runs on PRs from a development branch to `main` and you want to skip one of its steps if you merge `main` to your development branch, but you still run it if you push to that development branch. Right?

Comment: You should share your current workflow in the question to clarify the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for attempting to understand my poorly written question. I just updated the descriptions and added an example workflow. Hope it becomes a bit clearer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to run this step only when a PR against the `main` branch is merged, (therefore, when the `main` branch is updated after merging a PR), right?

Comment: Yup, that is correct!